# Number of events occurred on each hour in particular day

Tags: django, django-models

I have model containing "caller_name" and "call_datetime" field.

I was able to get number of calls occurred on each day in particular month:

```
while start_date <= end_date:
    calls = CDR.objects.filter(start_time__year=str(start_date.year), start_time__month=str(start_date.month), 
                                    start_time__day=str(start_date.day))
    print "Number of calls:", len(calls)
    start_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Similarlly, I tried to get number of calls on each hour in particular date.

```
for i in range(24):
    calls = CDR.objects.filter(start_time__year=str(start_date.year), start_time__month=str(start_date.month),start_time__day=str(start_date.day), start_time__hour=str(i))
```

Found out that "start_time__hour" is not implemented, but in their any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this workaround:

```
day_calls = CDR.objects.filter(start_time__year=str(start_date.year), start_time__month=str(start_date.month),start_time__day=str(start_date.day))

hour_calls = day_calls.extra(select={'hours': 'DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%%H")'})\
                      .values_list('hours', flat=True)\
                      .distinct()\
                      .order_by('hours')
```

Comment: I wanted the structure to be in this way - "hour","number of calls".
To achieve this, executed following series of queries:

`day_calls = CDR.objects.filter(start_time__year=str(start_date.year), start_time__month=str(start_date.month),start_time__day=str(start_date.day))`

`hour_calls = day_calls.extra(select={'hours': 'DATE_FORMAT(start_time, "%%H")'}).values('hours')`

`hour_calls.query.add_count_column()`

`hour_calls.query.group_by = ["hours"]`

Now "hour_calls" displays my required data.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use raw SQL with the `.extra()` method or something like this:

```
for i in range(24):
    dt1 = start_time.replace(hour=i)
    dt2 = dt1 + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    calls = CDR.objects.filter(start_time__gte=dt1, start_time__lt=dt2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I could try this, but it's going to take huge time as there are millions of record.